# Что надо знать о плотности пикселов веб-дизайнеру?

Tags: html, css, веб-дизайн, оптимизация-сайтов

На разных экранах картинка может отображаться по-разному, в зависимости от плотности пикселов. Как добиться качественного отображения растровой графики на экранах с разной плотностью пикселов?

Нашёл [руководство](https://habrahabr.ru/post/237931/), но хотелось бы ещё приёмов верстки (HTML и CSS).

**UPD**: нашёл ещё одну [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/150071/). Получается примерно так:

```
.icon {
  background-image: url(example.png);
  background-size: 200px 300px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
  .icon {
    background-image: url(example@2x.png);
  }
}
```

**UPD2**: 1 dppx (pixel ratio) = 96 ppi.

Answer (score 0):

Для примера :
в HTML5 для тега IMG добавлены такие атрибуты:

```
<img alt="image" src="item.jpeg" srcset="item-HD.jpeg 2x, banner-phone.jpeg 640w, banner-phone-HD.jpeg 640w 2x" />
```

т.е если вы поняли что я говорю о scrset

но и мимо css не прошли и было добавлено img-set:

```
background-image: -webkit-image-set (url(icon1x.jpg) 1x,url(icon2x.jpg) 2x );
```

Это говорит браузеру, что есть два изображения на выбор. Один из них оптимизирован для 1x дисплеев, а другой для 2x дисплеев.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но что подставлять вместо 1x и 2x? Имею в виду, 192dpi и т.п.?

Comment: это картинка умножить на 2, просто проверьте на мониторе с большим dpi к примеру на retina

Comment: вот кстати статья на эту тему : https://htmlhook.ru/peremennaya-plotnost-pikselej.html